# Multithreaded File polling

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a program which picks file from disk using JNotify and loads it in a blocking queue (say newQueue). I have two demon threads running in while(true) loop. One thread keep looking for file present in the new queue (where JNotify puts the file) using take() and once received pass it to ThreadPoolExecutor for processing.
The threadpoolexecutor maintains set of worker thread and execute the command. The worker thread simply parse the file and insert the data into DB. If everything works fine the status will be updated to success else to failure. 
Now this thread will put the file on another blocking queue (say moverQueue) for further processing.

The second demon thread keep pooling this mover queue using take(), and once file arrives pass it to its own Threadpoolexecutor for processing. Depending on the status the file will be moved to separate location.
Now once the work finishes I will stop both thread pool and hence both demon threads will also stop.

The problem here is I have a retry logic  and in case some recoverable processing fails, the file is again put on the new Queue with retry count incremented.

I could not find any elegant way to decide if my work is finished and its okay to shut down the thread pools. I can not rely on file count as some files may fail. My demon thread maintains the thread pool and has no idea about the retry because that's being handled by the worker threads.

Please suggest solution also if this design approach is fine or not . I have large amount of files say 40K coming at once.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you already have some simple flag for knowing when files have stopped coming into your program, and you just need to make sure the ones already in your program are handled before shutting down.

You can do this by adding all files to a set "filesToHandle" when they come in, and removing the file when it has been *successfully* handled by a worker thread.

When you remove the file from the set, if the flag is `true` and your `filesToHandle` set is now empty, you can shut down the executor.  Similarly, if when you set the flag to true the set is empty, shut down the executor immediately.

Be sure to synchronize these operations to avoid any race conditions.

Really this is no different from maintaining a file count.  I'm not sure why you think that's not a viable option.  Somewhere your code decides whether to retry or not depending on whether the processing was successful.  Just make sure you only decrement the count on **success**.

Comment: I am already maintaining a queue for all incoming files, from where the demon thread is taking the file and passing it to the worker thread.Are you suggesting for keep another set having same list of files ? I can not check or terminate the executor if my new queue becomes empty as on failure my worker thread is putting the file back on the new queue so that another worker thread can process it.There will be chances when the queue becomes empty but the worker threads are stil running and can put a file back on the queue in case of failure.Queue is empty doesn't reflect the work has finished